# Merging branch to multiple branches in Git

Tags: git, merge, branch, branching-and-merging

Suppose, I have multiple branches: `feature_1`, branched from `HEAD` of `master`, then `feature_2` branched from `HEAD` of `feature_1` and `feature_3` branched from `HEAD` of `feature_2`.

And then I discover a bug in `feature_1`. I fix it and commit, now `feature_2` and `feature_3` still contain this bug. One way to fix this is to merge `feature_1` onto `feature_2` and `feature_3`.

Is this right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cherry picking is mostly used exactly for what you described.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-cherry-pick

Comment: On a remote repo cherry-picking would be better way, I guess, so I mark that answer as right, as it is more universal. Rebasing a remote repo would be troublesome.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, merging is one possible solution. However, this creates merge commits if you can live with that. However, if you want to avoid those merge commits a cleaner approach is to rebase the feature_2 and feature_3 branches.

I'd refrain from using cherry-pick since it creates new commits with the same content on multiple branches. I'd only use cherry-pick if I fixed a serious bug on e.g. feature_1 but want it on master as well, without having to merge the complete feature branch into master just to get that fix.